# What standards should be followed while deploying a new Linux/Solaris server in production

Tags: installation, deployment

I am trying to setup a standard for deploying new servers in production. I want to include some default tools to be installed on every server like snmp,nmap,vim,nano and on the same time want to remove all the unwanted tools,services which are not required like avahi-daemon,sendmail,cups etc. Basically it depends on the purpose or function of the server. But still want some idea on this part for very basic server deployment. It also includes the default partition schema.

Can anybody please help me with this, if anybody already using it.

Comment: Personally I cannot suggest what to have by default as it depends on your environment but making sure that SNMP is available can help for remote monitoring :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSA is a good starting point for creating your own standard.

http://www.nsa.gov/ia/guidance/security_configuration_guides/operating_systems/linux.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can automate some of the steps using shell scripts. For example, you can include the tools/packages to be installed. For debian-based systems, you can one `apt-get install` command.

You can use the same partitioning schema for the **common partitions** on all servers. Service-related partitions need to be customized and documented.

You can write all these steps in a document and follow it when doing the installation.

Comment: Yes Khaled you are right. I need that doc or steps that needs to be follow before,while,after installation. I just finished first version of my doc. I wanted to find some reff. to complete my doc.